# NLCD WMS Server Returns Color Index Instead of Classification Code

Tags: wms, getmap, nlcd

When I use the WMS service to download a region of the NLCD 2016 dataset the service returns a geotif with **color index** value and not **classification code**.  The image successfully loads in ArcMap or QGIS and is rendered using the appropriate style.  However, when I identify individual cells to check their values I get **color index** and not **classification code.**

Furthermore,  I can use the online [viewer](https://www.mrlc.gov/viewer/) and download a similar image using the draw tool.  When I do this the downloaded image contains the correct style and classification codes instead of color index. This is desired output I am looking for from WMS service.

Should my query be adjusted to return the correct value (classification) instead of color code?

Ex. query -

https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/mrlc_display/NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48/ows?version=1.3.0&service=WMS&layers=NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48&styles&crs=CRS:84&format=image/geotiff8&request=GetMap&width=226&height=100&BBOX=-101.462828,35.636649,-101.456214,35.638981&

Comment: @user2856 There is but one service.  Is there no service for land cover that would allow

Comment: .. users to extract the values from a bbox? (Sorry posting from mobile and could not find an edit option).

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton.  But if the picture is a raster (tiff) . The values are not also present? Just confirming.

Comment: It is just a picture encoded as a tiff (or a jpeg, png, pdf, etc)

Comment: Try https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/mrlc_display/NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48/ows?service=WCS&request=getCapabilities to get coverages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120209/discussion-between-wtgeographer-and-ian-turton).

Comment: @IanTurton I would like to mark the WCS alternative as a correct answer.  If you agree can you post your comment as answer?